# Largest Singular value of a Matrix

Tags: matrices, svd

Prove that if $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, then

$$\sigma_{\text{max}} (A) = \underset{y\in\mathbb{R}^m\\x\in \mathbb{R}^n}{\text{max}}\frac{y^TAx}{\Vert{x}\Vert_2\Vert y\Vert_2}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have (for nonzero $x$ and $y$)
$$
\frac{y^TAx}{\|x\|_2\|y\|_2}\leq\frac{\|y\|_2\|Ax\|_2}{\|y\|_2\|x\|_2}=\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}.
$$
If one picks $y=Ax$, it gives
$$
\left.\frac{y^TAx}{\|x\|_2\|y\|_2}\right|_{y=Ax}=\frac{x^TA^TAx}{\|x\|_2\|Ax\|_2}
=\frac{\|Ax\|_2^2}{\|x\|_2\|Ax\|_2}=\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}.
$$
Since the quotient can be bounded from above independently of $y$ and this bound is attained by some $y$, we have that
$$
\max_{x,y}\frac{y^TAx}{\|x\|_2\|y\|_2}=\max_{x}\frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}.
$$
Now this is the standard variational characterisation of $\sigma_{\max}(A)$:
$$
\max_x\frac{\|Ax\|_2^2}{\|x\|_2^2}=\max_x\frac{x^T(A^TA)x}{x^Tx}=\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)=\sigma_{\max}^2(A).
$$